# Formatting date in domForm.toJson in dojo

Tags: dojo

In my Web Application i have changed my `dijit/form/DateTextBox` date format using `constraints="{datePattern:'MM/dd/yyyy'}"` attribute,
But when i call the form containing the `dijit/form/DateTextBox` using `domForm.toJson` the format is changed to `yyyy/dd/MM`

why?
How to solve it

Comment: Check this [Getting different date pattern when using dojo.formToJson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35102794/2932476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dijit/Form/DateTextBox** is a **dojo/widget** not **dom**.

**domForm.toJson** access **Dom**'s value not **Dijit** widget's **get('value')** function which gives you a formatted output as you expect.

To get correct value - Use **Dijit/Form** and then use **form.get("value")**

[Dijit Form](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Form.html)

Comment: is it possible to convert dijit form elements to json like domform

Comment: @nithinalways yes, indeed, form.get("value") returns an object